# Update Maven Version

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

How can we update the version of maven in a java project.

I have tried changing the version in pom.xml file but that is leading to build failures when PR is raised. What other things can be done to change the version?

I want to change this and update the version to 3.8.8

```
<requireMavenVersion>
   <version>3.3.9</version>
</requireMavenVersion>
```

Comment: afaik Maven doesn't self-update. You need to get the version you need

Comment: Yes, it does not. So this project that I am working on is using an outdated version of Maven and thus I want to update it in a Pull Request. Looking a solution for that.

Comment: As I said, you need to get (download or otherwise) and use the version you need https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi?.

Comment: What do you mean by PR.  Pull request?  Please use the full word so that we know what you are saying.

Comment: This way the version will be updated in my locals only, I want to change it for all other users as well.

Comment: If you mean "pull request" ... what you want to do cannot be done.  No matter how many times you say that you need it.  The "other users" will need to update their installation of Maven too.

Comment: Does that mean if once we have used a certain maven version for a project (in this case a remote repository), we will have to stick to that version forever and if we want to change the version we can only do it individually by installing the required version?

Comment: Reframing the question - How can we update the CI to have a new version of Maven?

Comment: Do you use maven wrapper (mvnw) or a pre-installed maven on the CI? Which CI do you use? (please add the answers directly to your question, as they are relevant for an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done.  Maven cannot update itself.  You ... and the other people building your project ... will need to update the version of Maven in the normal way:

- If you / they are running builds on workstations, etc, use the platform's package installer or whatever to update Maven,
- If you are doing builds on a CI system, you may need to update the installed Maven on the CI server.  Ask the admin to do it.
- If you are publishing your project, put the required Maven version into the project's build instructions / README file.

---

> Does that mean if once we have used a certain maven version for a project (in this case a remote repository), we will have to stick to that version forever

No ...

> and if we want to change the version we can only do it individually by installing the required version?

Yes.  Or on the CI server if that is what you are using.

You should avoid specifying a tight Maven version constraint in your POM file.  Use version ranges (see the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html)) ... or no version constraint at all.  (Typically, Maven builds are largely insensitive to the Maven version that is used.)

---

> How can we update the CI to have a new version of Maven?

Read the CI system documentation.  That will explain what you need to do.  Or talk to the person who manages it for you.

Comment: thank you so much